# How to append an image to a rails object dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, object, dynamic, append

How can I append an image to a model object in rails? For example, if I had a post, how could I upload/append an image to the object so that I can call it in the view dynamically? I know that the association would be a has_one relationship... Ive looked around and just can't find anything on this topic. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest using Paperclip: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Do you mind accepting this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The most common solution for model attachments in Rails is the [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). Try using it, or take a look at a [corresponding Ruby Toolbox category](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads).